# There are 68 rooms in a hotel with either 2 or 3 beds. There are 161 beds in total. How many 2 and 3 bed rooms are there in the hotel?

Tags: linear-algebra

There are 68 rooms in a hotel with either 2 or 3 beds. There are 161 beds in total. How many 2 and 3 bed rooms are there in the hotel?

How do I solve expressions like this?

Comment: write it as 2x+3y=161

Comment: Sorry for the noobish question. But I have no idea. :-(

Comment: And we have $x+y=68$. Multiply this with $2$ and subtract the emerging equation from the equation $2x+3y=161$, you immediately get $y$

Comment: Now solve the linear equation system.

Comment: "How to solve expressions like this?" Actually there are no expressions (yet) and solving this is for a big deal a matter of finding expressions (as done by Roddy and Peter). You can see that as making a mathematical model of the described realities.

Comment: Linear equations are overkill for this sort of thing.  Easier to just remark that every room has at least $2$, so that's $2\times 68=136$ beds accounted for.  The rest have to come from those rooms with three beds.

Comment: @lulu Nice shortcut, but the expression $161-2\cdot 68$ can be found easily with the linear equation system as well. Is there a useful generalization to find such shortcuts ?

Comment: @lulu it still comes to the same answer.  it's still using the arguments given. peter yes take the minimum number of beds per room subtract that times number of rooms from total number of beds and you get the number of beds that are made from the other number of bed per rooms.

Comment: @Peter  Well, as a general combinatorial trick, I often find it useful to discard all the common terms.  They are fully accounted for, hence do nothing but clutter the arithmetic.  With just two unknowns, that's almost always enough.  For more unknowns, at least it simplifies the arithmetic.

Comment: of course this shortcut depends on a few things if it were 2 and 4 bed per room and 160 you have multiple solutions possible. ( okay at least without the number of rooms part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the number of 2-bed rooms, $y$ the number of 3-bed rooms. 161 beds in total means $2x+3y=161$, and there are 68 rooms so $x+y=68$.

Since you've tagged this as linear algebra, this is the system in matrix-form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}68\\161\end{bmatrix}$$

Row-reduce and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $x$ be the number of $2$ bed rooms and $y$ be the number of $3$ bed rooms. Then

$$\begin{align}x+y&=68 \\
2x+3y&=161.
\end{align}$$

Can you see why?